# Bitwise Operation For Conditional Inversion

Tags: bit-manipulation

I feel like there should be a simple bitwise operation that can accomplish this but for the life of me I can't think what it is:

```
final_value = do_invert ? !input : input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_value = do_invert ^ input;
```

where ^ is the exclusive OR (XOR)

Comment: okay, I'm an idiot - I just tested that and I accidentally had my expected output wrong... lol, thanks :)